# Using Margin or Padding with LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-linearlayout

I'm having trouble lining up a LinearLayout in a XML file. I'm trying to use a LinearLayout because I have TextViews that have to be hidden/shown upon certain options being selected, which I have that down. My problem is that I'm trying to use margin to line everything up centered, but if I run it on my Pixel 5 emulator, it's shift to the right when I have everything centered in my XML. Should I be using padding instead in my LinearLayout, or what should I be doing? Thank you!

**App Screen**

[image]

**XML Design**

[image]

**dialog_job_request_confirmation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BF090909">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="560dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_view"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@color/main_purple"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="125dp"
                            android:layout_height="56dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/skedaddle_service_logo"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/skedaddle_services_"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar_layout">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/confirmJobRequestLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="495dp"
                                android:text="@string/confirm_job_request_details"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/fullnameLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:text="@string/full_name_"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/fullnameDetailLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/addressLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="115dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:text="@string/address_"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/addressDetailLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dateAndTimeLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:text="@string/dates_and_times_"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/firstDateAndTimeDetailLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/secondDateAndTimeDetailLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/thirdDateAndTimeDetailLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/timeConstraintsLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:text="@string/time_constraints_"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/timeConstraintsDetailLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/jobDescriptionLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="115dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:text="@string/job_description_"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/jobDescriptionDetailLabelTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/cancelConfirmJobButton"
                                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                                    android:background="@color/black"
                                    android:text="@android:string/cancel"
                                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/confirmJobRequestButton"
                                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                                    android:background="@color/main_purple"
                                    android:text="@string/confirm_job"
                                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                </ScrollView>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't center anything using just padding or margin. In your case it's enough to use the layout_gravity in each TextView:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_gravity).

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! What do I use for lining up the two buttons?

Comment: You could wrap them into a ConstraintLayout: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout
Or try with the Layout Weight from the LinearLayout:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#Weight